# how to add dependency in engines rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm trying to add a gem depency in my engine but it does not work.

Here is my setting.

1- admin.gemspec

```
s.add_dependency "font-awesome-rails"
```

2- lib/admin.rb

```
require "admin/engine"
require "font-awesome-rails"

module Admin
end
```

But when i try to use the gem function in the engine, I got a NoMethodError

Has this changed in rails 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a mountable engine? It worked for me in a non-mountable one, but I'm running into the same issue and noticed (without resolution):

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues?q=engine

Looks like we're all rolling our own admin tools these days...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Indeed it is a mountable engine, and there doesn't seem to be solution. Well this is a gem I can do without...